# Power BI IF Between 2 Times & Two Dates Then Date Otherwise Another Date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that pulls date, time and value. I want to create a column that puts the date

IF(time is between 7:00 a.m. and 7:00 pm. on the same day && time is between 7:00 p.m. (on the same day) and 7:00 a.m the next day, same day DATE, same day DATE -1.

The snippet below provides what the end result should be.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify this as follows:

```
EndResult =
IF (
    HOUR ( Table1[time] ) < 7,
    DATEVALUE ( Table1[time] ) - 1,
    DATEVALUE ( Table1[time] )
)
```